# Why Linux works but windows not?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, windows-installation, bad-sectors

I ran the command `badblocks` and it found 5 sector errors on my hard drive

It is preventing my windows installation from completing. After loading all the files, it is showing a blue screen error.

But why my ubuntu is functioning properly?

Comment: Any number of factors could result in Linux working and Windows not working including simple luck.  If you have bad sectors on your hdd you really should address that problem.  Tools like SpinRite can help with bad sectors on a hdd depending on the reason the sector  is actually bad.

Comment: It would help a lot if we knew what error Windows was getting.

Comment: Before formatting windows 7,i made a pre boot scan which resulted in

Error Code 0142 Msg : Error Code 2000-0142 Msg : 
Hard Drive 0 - self test unsuccessful. 
Status : 79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses a totally different filesystem and kernel.  Each filesystem has a set of sectors that have to be good in order for the file system to function properly.  If 1 of these crucial sectors are bad it will not format.  FAT file systems have a File allocation table if any of the sectors in this table are bad when formatting then formatting will fail.  NTFS has a different set of required sectors.

Comment: Yes, i was expecting an answer similar to this.
Your answer solved a lot of my confusions.
But now is there a way to map that crucial sector to any other good sector so that i can start using windows again?

Comment: SpinRite (cost money) or mhdd ( http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/ )

Comment: @IntelligentYahoo  (for mhdd) Use MAKELOG and turn REMAP on. Read this: http://real-world-systems.com/docs/MHDD_en_manual.html

Comment: can i make MHDD bootable from a pendrive?

Comment: @IntelligentYahoo  A program called UNETBOOTIN might allow you to convert the ISO to a bootable USB.  There is probably other software out there.